# Box2D-like collision of lots of circles

Tags: c++, collision

I am trying to write a very stripped down, simple collider similar to Box2D-- absent all physics, rotation, etc.  I'm doing this both to keep the code footprint tiny and understandable, and also to simply learn the inner workings of these things personally.

All I'm trying to do is collide circles and lines, and keep them from getting embedded in eachother.

Box2D does this almost perfectly-- very tiny amounts of overlap!  However, when I write my own simple simulator, I get a lot of overlap: [image: picture of overlapped circles].

When I run the same simulation using Box2D (this is just all circles chasing a point in the center of the screen), I get no visible overlap at ALL.

In pseudocode, this is what I do:

```
For each Circle In List:
    Determine who will collide with the circle in next step
    Sort collisions by closest first
    For each possible collision:
        Add the unembed vector to the Circle's movement vector

...and then:

For each Circle In List:
    At the movement to the circle
```

So, if the circles don't get pushed into anything else, this also works perfectly.  When things pile up, though, it does NOT work, and I know why-- the unembeds simply accumulate and everyone pushes and jostles because later circles get unembedded into earlier circles, and at the end of the simulation, some are just stuck inside others.  Makes enormous sense.

Here's where I'm confused:
Near as I can tell, Box2D operates EXACTLY the same way-- get possible collisions, unembed from eachother, done.  But Box2D never, ever, gets overlapping like mine (or it gets them so small as to not matter).

Can someone tell me what step I have missed here?  I can do tweaking to improve things (like iterating anyone who collided again and again... but Box2D does not appear to do this, and I want to understand while keeping the code light and fast).

Thanks!

Pertinent real code below:

```
aO->mPos = x,y of object
aO->mMove = x,y of movement this step
aO->mRadius = radius of object
aO->MovingBound() = bound of object including the move

void Step() 
{
EnumList(MCObject,aO,mMovingObjectList)
{
    mTree.GetAllNearbyObjects(aO->MovingBound().Expand(aO->mRadius/4),&aHitList);
    aHitList-=aO; // Remove self from list
    if (aHitList.GetCount()>0)
    {
        // Sort the collisions by closest first
        if (mSortCollisions)
        {
            // Snip, took this out for clarity...
            // It just sorts aHitList by who is closest
            // to the current object
        }
        // Apply the unembedding
        EnumList(MCObject,aO2,aHitList) CollideObjectObject(aO,aO2);
    }
}

// Do the actual moves
EnumList(MCObject,aO,mMovingObjectList)
{
    mTree.Move(aO->mProxy,aO->Bound(),aO->mMove);
    aO->mPos+=aO->mMove;
    aO->mMove=0;
}
}


void CollideObjectObject(MCObject* theO1, MCObject* theO2)
{
float aOverlap=gMath.DistanceSquared(theO1->mPos+theO1->mMove,theO2->mPos+theO2->mMove);
float aMixRadius=theO1->mRadius+theO2->mRadius;
if (aOverlap<=aMixRadius*aMixRadius)
{
    Point aUnembed=(theO1->mPos-theO2->mPos);
    float aUnembedLength=aMixRadius-sqrt(aOverlap);
    aUnembed.SetLength(aUnembedLength);
    float aMod=.5f;
    if (theO2->mCollideFlags&COLLIDEFLAG_STATIONARY) aMod=1.0f;

    theO1->mMove+=aUnembed*aMod;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolving collisions between many objects is quite a difficult problem because, in addition to the basic maths of collisions, you have to work much more diligently at fixing the accumulation of mathematical errors that come from approximative solvers (physics in the real world work based on integration which dictates infinitesimally small time-steps; while in our simulations, we usually only solve some 60 times a second).

Let's have a look at [Box2D's constraint solver loop, located in b2island.cpp](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/374664b2a4ce2e7c24fbad6e1ed34bebcc9ab6bc/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Island.cpp#L260): In every world step, the collision resolver does not only run once. It will repeat `velocityIterations` times, which in the official test cases is usually set to 6 or 8. And that is what you will have to do as well.

Comment: Thanks-- I have actually tried this, and I do get better results.  It just seems very inefficient.  I did not know Box2D did this-- I looked it over but missed the reiteration. That's all I needed to know.

Comment: Would be a good idea to look at median error per iteration and see how more iterations reduce the error. Since you are using semi-implicit Euler , you should see a linear correlation between amount of iterations and error reduction.

Comment: Also, I just realized that I was citing the continuous solver, which is only used in the special case of "bullets" (very fast moving objects). Normally, objects only have discrete solver steps, which you can find in [`b2island::solve`](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/374664b2a4ce2e7c24fbad6e1ed34bebcc9ab6bc/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Island.cpp#L260). Turns out, they don't check for errors, but rather only repeat `velocityIterations` times, which is usually 6 or 8. Updated my answer. - Sorry about that!

Comment: So that explains nicely why if I just loop the iterations, it works like Box2d.  Because that's what Box2d works.

It's funny because, I come from a time when CYCLES MATTERED... it's a hard adaptation for me to simply go ahead and run what seems expensive code (it has sqrt for God's sake) six times in a single update.

So I was looking for the "elegant, Carmackian solution."  Turns out there isn't one, go figure. :)

Comment: @Raptisoft You are talking about a Quake-style "Carmackian" solution which barely needed any physics (you might want to check out [the Q3 code](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena), since as we all know, it was super smooth). I'm sure, the physics engine in Rage was rather complex. But another way of going full-Carmack would be to accept the fact that you cannot change the algorithmic requirements of a modern physics engine, and instead focus on getting the cycles back through cache-, [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) and TLP optimizations.

Comment: @Domi Isn't it the position iterations that resolve overlap (not velocity iterations)? I think you need to edit that.